# Wordpress URI hook "before post search"

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to write a wordpress plugin that searches allows for the "third segment" of the URI   to be a parameter.

So for example my pretty links structure looks like: `%category%/%postname%`

I've got a category for "myplugin" and a post called "myitem"
this would be accessible via: `/myplugin/myitem`

I need to be able to add a third parameter: `/myplugin/myitem/the_item_identifier`

Within the hook I'll have some logic to handle this case, something like

```
function myplugin_hook_before_uri_read(){
    $fields = explode('/',$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
        if (count($fields) == 4 && $fields[1] == "myplugin" && $fields[2] == "myitem") {
            // fix things so we're redirected into the correct post.
    }
}
```

to be fair, I could probably manage the same effect by using the URI
     /myplugin/myitem/?the_item_identifier

So maybe it's not the end of the world.  Though I'd feel a lot cleaner if I could work without the `?`

Also - if there's a better way then adding a hook, please speak up about that.  I'm not married to the method, it's just the only way I can think to achieve it.

**EDIT** in response to Chris' question below,

in this case, `the_item_identifier` is the primary key from a third party XML document.

So for example, if it was a list of products,  I'd have a single post that was a "display template" for the product.

Answer (score 0):

What do you plan to use for "the_item_identifier"? There is already an option built into the wordpress dashboard that allows you to make custom permalinks. I often use:

/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/

Check out the [WordPress Permalinks page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) for a list of options to use between the %% to make your custom permalink structure.

Comment: thanks for the question Chris, the_item_identifier is a primary key from a third party API.

Comment: I don't have time to read through the whole thing now, but this might be useful:http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite